# Access context param from a class inside lib jar

Tags: java, class, param

Is it possible to access a context param from a jar in lib or from a normal java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which framework you are using but assuming you are using `HttpServlet` you can use `getServletContext` method to retrieve the `ServletContext` and then you can retrieve context parameters by `getInitParameter(String)` method.

```
ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
String dbDriver = ctx.getInitParameter( "your_parameter_name" );
```

You can read more about [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html), [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) and [getServletContext method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29).